# Selecting rows that only have one unique relationship between two columns DBMS SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a single query to select all rows that have one unique relationship between two columns.

for example:

```
1   2   3   4
-------------
a   t   g   1
a   f   d   1
b   h   l   2
b   r   g   2
b   q   m   3
```

Here, I'm only looking at columns 1 and 4.

In this table, I would want to select rows 1 and 2 because in both of them, column 1 = a and column 4 = 1. in other words, every time a occurs in column one, 1 occurs in column four. I would not want to select any rows containing b for column 1 because those corresponding values for column 4 could either be 2 or 3.

Comment: The table is so large I cant look for specific occurrences. I need to write a query to select when the described condition above occurs. Also, with this logic, "where col1 = 'b' and col4 = '2'" would return rows I do not want because there is a row where col1 = b and col4 = 3.

Comment: I think what you want is a list of those rows, where the value of column `4` only depends on the value of column `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get column 1 values that satisfy your requirement with this query:

```
SELECT col1
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col4) = 1
```

So, your final query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 IN 
(
    SELECT col1
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY col1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col4) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
select *
from my_table
where "1" in (
  select c1
  from (
    select "1" as c1, count("4") as cnt
    from my_table
    group by "1" -- fixed here.
    having count("4") > 1
  ) x
  group by c1
  having count(cnt) = 1 -- this is the key condition.
)
```

Considering your column names do not start with a letter, most databases will accept them if you enclose them in double quotes (`"`), as I did.

Comment: im getting an error that says "1" must appear in the group by clause. My columns in the database are letter based. I just used numbers for posting purposes

Comment: Yes, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

It you want to select the actual rows, then use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.c1 = t.c1 and t2.c4 <> t.c4);
```

If you just want the `c1` values then use `group by` as suggested by other answers.